# app_remove firebase event count for Android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, event-tracking, android-event

Need help understanding the *app_remove* event from the firebase analytics report for my Android app.

[image: app_remove from analytics.google.com/]

It shows **total 9 users**

**3 app_remove** events

**3 users** for whom the **app_remove** event occured

And the **event count per user** is mentioned as *3*

- If we compare with similar first_open event (similar because it
  occurs only once per user), the event count per user comes to 1.
- If some user did remove the app 3 times, there should a corresponding
  first_open event.
- There are no notifications and custom events in for
  the app, those can cause interference.

I have read the Documentation https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en

But, I do not understand what is happening?

Since this being a crucial event for the app developer, please explain.